# Laravel Mediable - deleting media along with physical file

Tags: laravel-5

Using [Laravel Mediable](https://github.com/plank/laravel-mediable) and I'm trying to figure out the best way to delete an individual file. Say there's a list of files when I'm viewing the parent Model, and I click a delete icon to make an ajax request to delete file (which should remove both the corresponding Media object and the physical file...)

This works:

```
$path_parts = pathinfo($request->filename);
$attachment = Media::where('directory', $folder)
               ->where('filename', $path_parts['filename'])
               ->where('extension', $path_parts['extension'])
               ->first();
$attachment->delete();
```

but this deletes only the database row and not the physical file itself:

```
$attachment = Media::where('id', $request->fileid);
$attachment->delete();
```

I'd prefer deleting the file via the id because its unique but wondering what I'm missing...

Answer (score 1):

You must delete the file also using this code

> File::delete('path/to/'.$request->filename);

=updated=
The problem on the second block is just need to add ->first() at the end of the where clause

Comment: Actually that's not needed in this case - the beauty of using a package like this. See http://laravel-mediable.readthedocs.io/en/latest/mediable.html#deleting-mediables. Also, as mentioned above, it works fine with the first block vs the second block.

Comment: oh, then the problem on the second block is just need to add ->first() at the end of the where clause